# Why are function signatures in calldata not padded by 0s given the 32 bytes word size of the evm?

Tags: evm, calldata

the call data below corresponds to the following method call
MethodID: 0xa694fc3a
[0]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021192f2c6946a040

the calldata: 0xa694fc3a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021192f2c6946a040

Question, why is the function signature not padded by 0s to make it a 32 byte size evm word? the first arg is padded with 0s to make it 32 bytes long

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is the case is that if the first argument is being encoded to exactly four bytes, the argument is not padded to 32 bytes to allow the use of function signatures, see the [Solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#members-of-addresses).

The other possibility is that this is an internal function call which uses a different convention.